# How to pass variable from one view to another using render

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, render

In one view kat.phtml I have variable `$i` and I'd like to use this `$i` in another view `opinia.phtml`. How to pass this `$i` ?

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->allProd); $i++) : ?>
   <?php echo $this->render('oferta/opinia.phtml'); ?>
<?php endif ;?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `partial` - then you can pass additional variables:

```
$this->partial('oferta/opinia.phtml', array('i' => $i));
```

Comment: And how to use $i in opinia.phtml ?

Comment: exactly the same as in normal template